# function for event occurrence data in r

Tags: r, date

I have a patient data set i need to drop the rows after the first occurrence of disease column. for instance

```
ID    Date    Disease
123 02-03-2012  0
123 03-03-2013  1
123 04-03-2014  0
321 03-03-2015  1
423 06-06-2016  1
423 07-06-2017  1
543 08-05-2018  1
543 09-06-2019  0
645 08-09-2019  0
```

and the expected output i want

```
ID    Date     Disease
123 02-03-2012  0
123 03-03-2013  1
321 03-03-2015  1
423 06-06-2016  1
543 08-05-2018  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way with `dplyr` select rows till first occurrence of 1 for each `ID`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() <= which(Disease == 1)[1])


#    ID  Date        Disease
#  <int> <fct>        <int>
#1   123 02-03-2012       0
#2   123 03-03-2013       1
#3   321 03-03-2015       1
#4   423 06-06-2016       1
#5   543 08-05-2018       1
```

---

We can also use `slice`

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(if(any(Disease == 1)) 1:which.max(Disease) else 0)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 321L, 423L, 423L, 543L, 
543L, 645L), Date = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 
8L), .Label = c("02-03-2012", "03-03-2013", "03-03-2015", "04-03-2014", 
"06-06-2016", "07-06-2017", "08-05-2018", "08-09-2019", "09-06-2019"
), class = "factor"), Disease = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: thank dude it works perfectly in case of **NAs**  present in Disease column what should added in the code.

Comment: @Matrix_32 do you want to keep `NA`s or remove them? If you want to keep them the above code shuold work as it is but if you want to remove them you can just add `na.omit` in the end. `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(row_number() <= which(Disease == 1)[1]) %>% na.omit()`

Comment: i want to retain the patient ids with disease status 0 also with their minimum record date. How can I do that.

Comment: You mean `df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m-%d-%Y")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(if(any(Disease == 0)) which.min(Date) else 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why don't have the last line `645 08-09-2019  0` in your expected result. The first occurrence of disease column for ID 645 has not appeared yet, so I guess you might have missed it in your expected result.

Based on my guess above, maybe you can try the base R solution below, using `subset` + `ave`

```
dfout <- subset(df,!!ave(Disease,ID,FUN = function(v) !duplicated(cumsum(v)>0)))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   ID       Date Disease
1 123 02-03-2012       0
2 123 03-03-2013       1
4 321 03-03-2015       1
5 423 06-06-2016       1
7 543 08-05-2018       1
9 645 08-09-2019       0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 321L, 423L, 423L, 543L, 
543L, 645L), Date = c("02-03-2012", "03-03-2013", "04-03-2014", 
"03-03-2015", "06-06-2016", "07-06-2017", "08-05-2018", "09-06-2019", 
"08-09-2019"), Disease = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```